# Unable to hide the navigationBar when embedding SwiftUI in UIKit

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, swiftui

I am trying to hide the `navigationBar` when putting some SwiftUI inside of a UIKit `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
```

But it does not go away. When I take away the SwiftUI however, it works. Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Edit:**

I am instantiating a view like this:

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view())
```

where `view` is the SwiftUI and then adding this to the `UIView()` as you would any UIKit element.

Comment: Its works for me - In `viewWillAppear` if you hide it works but not in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 35):

UIHostingViewController respects the `navigationBarHidden` value of your SwiftUI view. You can either call `.navigationBarHidden(true)` at the end of your SwiftUI view, or you can use the custom UIHostingController subclass shown in the example below.

**Solution:**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class YourHostingController <Content>: UIHostingController<AnyView> where Content : View {

  public init(shouldShowNavigationBar: Bool, rootView: Content) {
      super.init(rootView: AnyView(rootView.navigationBarHidden(!shouldShowNavigationBar)))
  }

  @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

**Example of usage:**

```
let hostVc = YourHostingController(shouldShowNavigationBar: false, rootView: YourSwiftUIView())
```

Comment: I love u man. Hours of work, trying different things on UINavigationBar... and you saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.navigationBarHidden(true)` works, but the problem is it seems to also disable the "swipe from left side of screen to pop to previous vc" feature. Also, that modifier is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/navigationBarHidden(_:)).

Answer (score 25):

Using the modifier `.navigationBarHidden(true)` did not work in our case. It had no effect.

Our solution is to subclass `UIHostingController` and don't let it access the `UINavigationController` at all. For example:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

final public class RestrictedUIHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {

    /// The hosting controller may in some cases want to make the navigation bar be not hidden.
    /// Restrict the access to the outside world, by setting the navigation controller to nil when internally accessed.
    public override var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
        nil
    }
}
```

Note that this solution relies on underlying code in UIKit and SwiftUI accessing the `UINavigationController` and setting the navigation bar hidden state based on the `UIViewController.navigationController`-property. This may break in the future if Apple decides to change on this assumption.

Comment: This doesn't actually work on iOS 16 if you want to have nav bar items in your SwiftUI view - doing this apparently hides the SwiftUI nav bar as well, not just the UIKit one.

Comment: @DávidPásztor that's correct. This forces the navigation bar to be hidden – booth the one defined in UIKit and the one defined in SwiftUI. Hard to know for sure, but I think UIKit and SwiftUI uses the same navigation bar instance under the hood.

Comment: Worked great under iOS14, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Ran into this problem yesterday, too.

I am presenting a modal `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` as `rootViewController`, which embeds a SwiftUI View via `UIHostingController`.

Setting the usual `setNavigationBarHidden` in `viewDidAppear` of the `UIViewController` stops working as soon as the SwiftUI View is embedded.

Overview:

```
Root ViewController: setNavigationBarHidden in viewWillAppear

Navigation Bar Visible:
UINavigationController > root UIViewController > embedded UIHostingController

Navigation Bar Invisible:
UINavigationController > root UIViewController > no UIHostingController
```

After some debugging I realized that the `UIHostingController` itself calls `setNavigationBarHidden` again.

So the reason for this problem is, that the `UIHostingControllers` alters the surrounding `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar`.

One easy fix:

Set the Navigation Bar property in the first presented SwiftUI View that is embedded by your `UIHostingController`.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        MyOtherView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
```

This will revert the adjustment SwiftUI and the `UIHostingController` are trying to apply to your surrounding `UINavigationController`.

As there is no guarantee about the interaction between SwiftUI and UIKit (that it uses underlying UIKit), I would suggest keeping the `setNavigationBarHidden` in the surrounding `viewDidAppear` together with this modifier, too.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had to use this UIHostingController subclass.

```swift
class NavigationBarHiddenUIHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == false {
      navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a `UIHostingController` as a child of a `UIViewController` subclass, and I was hiding the navigation bar in the parent view controller's `viewWillAppear`, which was not working for the hosted SwiftUI. But moving my hiding to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` as you suggested her fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: …except that the nav bar still seems to be unhiding when you pop back to that view controller smh

Answer (score 9):

Hiding navigation bar from a class that is extending UIHostingController seems to work when setNavigationBarHidden is called in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: For me, this caused the view to jump.
Putting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews works without the jump

Answer (score 7):

I want to include my approach here just in case someone find it useful when working with SwiftUI.
I found out that the problem was that UIHostingController was overriding something on my declare of

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

So i just created a custom UIHostingController and used viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool):

```
class UIHostingViewControllerCustom:UIHostingController<YourView>{
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
  }
}
```

Then when you are adding that UIHostingController into your ViewController:

```
let hostingController = UIHostingViewControllerCustom(rootView: YourView())
hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
addChild(hostingController)
hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
hostingMapView.didMove(toParent: self)

//Constraints
hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -view.safeAreaInsets.top).isActive = true
hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -view.safeAreaInsets.bottom).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me so I added an observer to hide `navigationBar` in the parent view:

```
    private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        observer = navigationController?.observe(
            \.navigationBar.isHidden,
            options: [.new]
        ) { [weak self] _, change in
            guard change.newValue == false else { return }
            self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems fixed on iOS 16: if you add a symbolic breakpoint for `-[UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:]` and you `p $arg3` you'll find that it was nil (false) on iOS 14/15 and it's now 1 (true) on iOS 16, in case you did call `setNavigationBarHidden(true` somewhere before this internal call happens, i.e. the internal call doesn't overwrite your code anymore.

On iOS 14, @TParizek's solution works (modifier `.navigationBarHidden(true)`), but on iOS 15 I had to call `setNavigationBarHidden(true` on the first `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call.

Answer (score 1):

I used [SwiftUI introspect library](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to hide the extra navigation bar that was only showing for OS version lower than 16.

```
.introspectNavigationController(customize: { navigationController in
                navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you are making UIHostingViewController without UINavigationController, you would need to make some adaptions to the frame itself(actually to reduce its topAnchor to 48).
It appears that navigationBar spacing shows up only on next viewWillAppear and  layout of subviews.

Here is the solution that I have used for my UIHostingViewController.

Firstly, I have made function(inside of my UIHostingViewController) that would set origin(x,y) of my inner subview and set the constraints to self.view.
It has condition(to not do that every time, only when navigation bar spacing shows up):

```
    private var savedView: UIView?

private func removeAdditionalTopSpacing() {
    if view.subviews.count == 0  {
        return
    }
    
    var widgetFrame = view.subviews[0].frame
    let widgetStartingPoint = widgetFrame.origin.y
    widgetFrame.origin.y = 0
    widgetFrame.origin.x = 0
    
    self.view.subviews[0].frame = widgetFrame
    self.view.subviews[1].frame = widgetFrame
    
    if widgetStartingPoint > 0 {
        self.savedView = self.view

        self.savedView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.savedView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.savedView!.subviews[0].widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.savedView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.savedView!.subviews[0].heightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.savedView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.savedView!.subviews[0].centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.savedView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.savedView!.subviews[0].centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view = self.savedView
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Important note:
Reason why I have saved current view inside of private variable savedView is because of his existence and memory release. In this way it won't be lost when removeFromSuperView got called.
There are always 2 subviews of UIHostingViewController.view. One for content and another one for hit range. Both are moved for 48 points down when navigation bar spacing shows up.

There are two places where I have called it: viewDidAppear() and viewDidLayoutSubviews():

```
public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    removeAdditionalTopSpacing()
}

public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    removeAdditionalTopSpacing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to all here is my solution how to hide AND BACK navigation bar

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class HostingController <Content>: UIHostingController<AnyView> where Content : View {
private weak var previousViewController: UIViewController?
private var shouldShowNavigationBar: Bool
private let shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack: Bool

public init( rootView: Content, previousViewController: UIViewController?,
             shouldShowNavigationBar: Bool = false, shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack: Bool = true) {

    self.previousViewController = previousViewController
    self.shouldShowNavigationBar = shouldShowNavigationBar
    self.shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack = shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack

    super.init(rootView: AnyView(rootView))
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(!shouldShowNavigationBar, animated: false)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        strongSelf
            .previousViewController?
            .navigationController?
            .setNavigationBarHidden(!strongSelf.shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack, animated: false)
    }
}


@objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

How to use it:

```
let viewController = HostingController(rootView: view, previousViewController: previousViewController)
```

In case if you need all parameters make not default you can call:

```
let viewController = HostingController(rootView: view, previousViewController: previousViewController, shouldShowNavigationBar: false, shouldShowNavigationBarAfterBack: false)
```

`previousViewController` - it's a controller that make push of this new one controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler solution.
if you are using Xcode 15 beta,
You can rewrite func viewIsAppearing(_ animated: Bool) and implement Func viewIsAppearing (_ Animated: bool) to deal with hiding and appearing in the navigation bar, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will kill me for this, but it is, working lake a charm

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIView())
    let swiftuiView = hostingVC.view!
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            addChild(hostingVC)
    } else {
        print("Caues memory leak but no double navigation header")
    }
    view.addSubview(swiftuiView)
    hostingVC.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Do u know where you put in UIKit function inside of swiftUI ?

inside of

```
var body: some View {

}
```

you need to call your ViewControllerWrapper class that class need to include some methods in order to use your UIKit class. UIViewControllerRepresentable implementation its also need.

Comment: I think you have my issue reversed. I am trying to embed SwiftUI --> UIKit.

Comment: look at this maybe it will help you to find what you search

Comment: my problem is not one of adding the swiftUI to the view. But rather the fact that it carries with it an immoveable navigationBar.