# UIPageViewController swipe ignores SwiftUI's navigationBarHidden(true)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a SwiftUI app that needs a slider with hundreds of pages. Since there's no first-party solution that fits my needs, I've adapted `UIPageViewController`. Main use-case: the slider should allow tapping on its content which will (un)hide the navigation bar. The hiding works fine alone, but when I swipe while the navigation bar is hidden, it reappears.

How can I keep the navigation bar hidden based on `navigationBarHidden(hidden)`?

Step by step:

1. Tap to hide (the navigation bar is now hidden)
2. Swipe (still hidden)
3. Swipe (it appears)

[image: Demo video]

In most cases, it takes two swipes to unhide the bar, but sometimes it unhides after only one swipe.

Here's the SwiftUI part of the app:

```
struct ApplicationView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var hidden = false
    @State private var currentPage = 0

    var body: some View {
        PagerView(0..<100, currentPage: $currentPage) {
            Text("\($0)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture { hidden.toggle() }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(hidden)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.red.ignoresSafeArea())
    }

}
```

and the adapted `UIPageViewController`:

```
struct PagerView<Data: RandomAccessCollection, Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    private let data: Data
    @Binding var currentPage: Data.Index
    private let interPageSpacing: CGFloat
    private let content: (Data.Element) -> Page

    init(
        _ data: Data,
        currentPage: Binding<Data.Index>,
        interPageSpacing: CGFloat = 0,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Page
    ) {
        self.data = data
        self._currentPage = currentPage
        self.interPageSpacing = interPageSpacing
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
            options: [.interPageSpacing: interPageSpacing]
        )
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        let direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection

        if let previousViewController = uiViewController.viewControllers?.first as? PageViewController<Page> {
            guard previousViewController.index != currentPage else { return }
            direction = previousViewController.index < currentPage ? .forward : .reverse
        } else {
            direction = .forward
        }

        let page = context.coordinator.page(for: currentPage)
        uiViewController.setViewControllers([page], direction: direction, animated: true)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

        private var parent: PagerView

        init(_ parent: PagerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func page(for index: Data.Index) -> PageViewController<Page> {
            return PageViewController(rootView: parent.content(parent.data[index]), index: index)
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController
        ) -> UIViewController? {
            guard parent.currentPage > parent.data.startIndex else { return nil }
            return page(for: parent.data.index(parent.currentPage, offsetBy: -1))
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController
        ) -> UIViewController? {
            guard parent.currentPage < parent.data.index(parent.data.endIndex, offsetBy: -1) else { return nil }
            return page(for: parent.data.index(parent.currentPage, offsetBy: 1))
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
            transitionCompleted completed: Bool
        ) {
            if completed, let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? PageViewController<Page> {
                parent.currentPage = viewController.index
            }
        }

    }

    class PageViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {

        var index: Data.Index

        init(rootView: Content, index: Data.Index) {
            self.index = index
            super.init(rootView: rootView)
        }

        @MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = .clear
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you're embedding a `UIHostingController`. I've found that having that as a child view will cause the navigation bar to reappear, because under some circumstances it sets hidden to false (not sure when).

Try the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131226/305973), removing access to `UINavigationController` from your `UIHostingController`:

```swift
class PageViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {

    public override var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
        nil
    }

    ...
}
```

(This is really something Apple should fix. At the moment `UIHostingController` doesn't really play nicely when embedded within a SwiftUI view hierarchy.)

Answer (score 0):

`i was a quick solution,but i'm not very sure  :)`

7/25/2022 update

```
  return TabView{
                 viewone
                 viewTwo

        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
```

update solution

```
  //your code 
  var body: some View {
        PagerView(0..<100, currentPage: $currentPage) {
            Text("\($0)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

                // page contain evey text in UIHostingController      
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .onTapGesture { hidden.toggle() }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(hidden)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.red.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
```

be like: a -> b

a:

```
NavigationView{
    let b = controller
    b.navigationBarHidden(true)
    link:b
}
```

b:

`i use a navigationView{} to contain my UI code in b`

```
//wrong!! can not a <- b
NavigationView {
    ZStack{
       custom navigationBar
       pageController
       ...
    }

}
```

```
//can a <- b
ZStack{
       custom navigationBar
       //just page
       NavigationView {
          pageController
       }
      
       ...
}
```

then,it solve a -> b temporary
just a trick,i haven't spend time digining

`another solution`, it works for me（2/16/2022）but not working in iOS 15

```
        let a = AnyView(TestRedView()).navigationBarHidden(true)
        let b = AnyView(TestBlueView()).navigationBarHidden(true)
        
        return PaginationView(pages: [a, b])
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```