# UIHostingController resets custom leftBarButtonItem when pushed

Tags: swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I have a view controller in a navigation controller. In `viewDidLoad`:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(Theme.Icon28.back.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBackButton), for: .touchUpInside)
button.imageEdgeInsets = Constants.buttonImageEdgeInsets
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "nav_btn_back"

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

This sets up my custom back button. Now I want to push a `UIHostingController`:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(UIHostingController(rootView: SomeView()), animated: true)
```

With `SomeView` as:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Now when I push the `UIHostingController` the back button will change back to the default system back button, the `leftBarButtonItem` has lost my custom button. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Why is it overriding my custom button?

Comment: you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782757/8351061) once.

Comment: Every view controller has own navigation item, you change for one, then push another, by default hosting controller as it is UIViewController provides default back button. Override UIHostingController and setup custom back button for it as well.